# Are all packages bundled and installed with iso file of ubuntu - which are in <eg: xenial > main?

Tags: apt, repository, live-cd

I have installed oneiric ocelot (Ubuntu 11.10). Its "main" repository (which I found in ISO image with Packages.gz name) contains `gfortran` but the gfortran command is not working i.e. it is not installed. My assumption is it is not enabled/installed as part of default installation but it is there in the image/iso file of Ubuntu 11.10.

Now I want to find any way to get the `gfortran` package from the image, but I doubt my assumption that all software packages which are in main repository will be part of the Ubuntu installation image. Please confirm and explain.

Comment: Where do you find this Packages.gz

Comment: Whoever closing this question as off-topic as EOL, please __stop__. This question is not _specific_ to 11.10 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your assumption is not correct. All softwares from main repository aren't included in Ubuntu live image and cannot be. They are huge!

`Packages.gz` is the package index file which is consulted when you input a command to install a package, to locate that package file in the Internet. Having `gfortran` in the file means it is available in repository and can be installed by downloading from Internet (not from the ISO).

Normally the iso image includes a subset of the main repository index file for some unknown reason. Live image also includes some packages in deb format in `/pool` directory. But these aren't all of the main repository.

Comment: Perfectly answered my question. Thank you Anwar.